# WWDC2010 Game Demo, programmers use what format for 3D model and animation?

Tags: apple

People in Apple Corporation make Quest game demo for WWDC in year 2010:

• Game Design and Development for iPhone OS, Part 1 · Session 401

• Game Design and Development for iPhone OS, Part 2 · Session 402

Youtube video of play game: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X4Ha-vhjrds

What format they use for load models and animation for models? This before SceneKit.

Link for video and PDF is here (but require Apple Developer Account for watch video):
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387070/apple-has-just-unlisted-all-its-2010-2011-videos-what-now-for-the-broken-links

Comment: Doesn't this question involve technologies that are still in use?  If so, then it is not a retrocomputing question.

Comment: OpenGL ES 2.0 came out 13 years ago, backwards compatibility seemed to be maintained thence, and iOS only deprecated OpenGL 2 years ago. Doesn't seem retro at all. StackOverflow or GameDev would be the appropriate places to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Voted as per DrSheldon’s concern, as the primary API being demonstrates there is OpenGL ES 2.0, which is now long gone from iOS but had been introduced a year earlier with the 3GS and survives today on Android and on the web as WebGL 1.0.

OpenGL is a low-level framework on top of which the programmer uses any file format they care to implement. In this case the speaker makes a big deal about projected lighting and character animation occurring on the GPU so you can be confident that they wrote their own engine for it, including the on-GPU code (which will have been in GLSL), especially given the quoted development time: two months with three programmers.

Unity was available for the iPhone even before programmable GPUs, but has its usual limitations; the Unreal Engine and other commercial-strength middleware didn’t really arrive until later that year. SceneKit didn’t arrive on iOS for another four years.